# floating module for joomla like in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

i have follwed this article to make a sticky sidebar for modules but this not work for me , how ca i fix this please ?

http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/sticky-sidebar-div-jquery-plugin.html

i have used this javascript to call the element sticky :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$.stickysidebarscroll("#<id_of_last_element>",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
</script>
```

and i have added this jquery.sticky-sidebar-scroll.min.js to the template

http://www.skipser.com/i/2/files/general/jquery.sticky-sidebar-scroll.min.js

this is how it should look :

like this https://www.screencast.com/t/M88RMOHQsoG6 in this theme :

http://magwp.thimpress.com/demo-11/the-development-of-digital-camera-in-the-digital-age/

you can deactivate the adbolck that you see that when you scroll down after 3 or 4 seconde the the sidebar start to scroll and then it stop after some secondes

thanks
 amine

Answer (score 0):

Replace "$" with "jQuery"

Joomla runs jquery in non-conflict mode because mootools also uses $.